# my code works fine with two selects but Im trying to use just one

Tags: php

I have a table "shedules" where I keep always two records(my shedules are saved in pdf format).

One record is relative to 1st year shedule, so my record is like:

**(id,pdf,year)** **(1,../uploads/shedules/1st_year.pdf, 1st_year)**

My othe record is like:

**(id,pdf,year)** **(2,../uploads/shedules/2nd_year.pdf, 2nd_year)**

My shedules are updated every week, but can be updated without a specific order, can first be updated schedule of the first year or second year.

And in my form, where I update my schedules, I also have two links to show 
current schedules of each year.

And I want to show on my link "See schedule 1st year" my schedule pdf of my 1st year, and I want to show on my link "See schedule 2nd year" my schedule pdf of my 2nd year.

Do you know how can I do that without doing two selects?? I already did with two selects but now Im trying to do only using one.

I was trying using "order by year asc" but dont works fine because the user that update shedules can insert first my 1st year or 2nd year...

```
<?php
    $readShedules = $pdo->prepare("SELECT pdf from schedules ORDER BY year ASC");
    $readShedules->execute();
    $result = $readShedules->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);     
    echo '<div>';
     echo '<a style="margin-right:10px;" href="../uploads/pdfs/'.$result['pdf'].'">See schedules 1st year</a>';
     echo '<a href="../uploads/pdfs/'.$result['pdf'].'">See schedule 2nd year</a>';
    echo '</div><!--viewcapa-->';  
?>
```

Comment: Are they UPDATED or just new row is inserted into table?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Nutic. If it first time that Im inserting shedules I do an insert. But then is always an update..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking to retrieve multiple rows from the database. If that's the case I'd point you toward the [PDO `fetchAll` method](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php), which retrieves all your matches for that query instead of `fetch` which retrieves just the first one.

Something along these lines:

```
$results = $readShedules->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo '<div>';
foreach( $results as $result ) {
    echo '<a style="margin-right:10px;" href="../uploads/pdfs/'.$result['pdf'].'">See schedules '.$result['year'].'</a>';
}
echo '</div><!--viewcapa-->';
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly with fetchAll method!

Comment: You're welcome :) Just remember that a database result set is just that, a set. To get multiple results from it, you'll need to use a method that retrieves multiple results, or use a loop with a method that returns a single one each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT year, pdf FROM [TableName] ORDER BY ID DESC
```

This will return you only 2 rows. And PDF value would be most recent update.
This is in case that every update makes new row in table.